# Delphi/Firedac/Firebird Get query performance info

Tags: delphi, firebird, query-performance, firedac

In the ibexpert tool, when executing a query, it shows the query performance info like this:

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 0ms
Execute time = 0ms
Avg fetch time = 0,00 ms
Current memory = 14*717*320
Max memory = 16*060*920
Memory buffers = 3*000
Reads from disk to cache = 69
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 572
```

I would like to get this information in my own tool, does anyone know how to get this information using Firedac en FDQuery on a Firebird 2.5 database in Delphi?

Comment: I'd say the [first group](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SQLEditor#QueryTime) is simply measured by the tool (like stopwatch). [Second group](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SQLEditor#Memory), if it's command related (not to database), then you can obtain this info from `MON$MEMORY_USAGE` monitoring table. [Third group](http://ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.SQLEditor#Operations) seems to be related to the command, and as such can be obtained from the `MON$IO_STATS` monitoring table. I couldn't find native API stuff for these statistics (if I got the meaning right).

Comment: @Victoria AFAIK, these statistics are not produced by the monitoring tables, but using the statement info API.

Comment: @Mark, which API function with which parameters then? I found nothing related to these statement statistics (browsing Firebird source).

Comment: Thanks for thinking along, so far i am not any closer, the only thing i did find out is how to get the query plan info, which index is being used on the query with such statement:
TIBStatement(qry_data.Command.CommandIntf.CliObj).sql_get_plan)

Comment: @Victoria `isc_dsql_sql_info` and `isc_database_info` with the `isc_info_*` request items. Note that some are not statement specific and may apply to the connection or even db in general.

Comment: @Mark, I'm aware of them. Which parameters, then? Here is their [declaration for current Firebird](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/blob/master/src/jrd/inf_pub.h). I couldn't find a single one for timing, none for statement related memory usage nor I/O stats. And this should be for Firebird 2.5 where can be even less features.

Comment: @Victoria I don't really have time to check that (hence my comments, and not a real answer). Timing is likely done in the application, not in Firebird, memory is probably `isc_info_current_memory`, and the IO stats `isc_info_reads`, `isc_info_writes` and `isc_info_fetches`.

Comment: @Mark, they are database related. And as such you cannot simply calculate them for a single SQL command (because there can be multiple clients executing other commands).

Comment: @Victoria True, but as far as I know some of the information displayed by IB Expert, Flamerobin, etc is not necessarily statement or connection specific.

Comment: @Mark, might be so. Hence I said _"if it's command related"_. I'm not sure what is displayed there. OP says in their title _"Get query performance info"_.

Comment: @Franky, could you be more specific about what kind of information do you want to get? I mean, write e.g. _**Avg fetch time** - average fetch time of multiple executions of a single command_, _**Current memory** - server memory usage_, _**Reads from disk to cache** - number of pages read for the executed command_, etc.

Comment: @Victoria well some values i can get another way, like the current free memory and Total memory but the purpose is most of all to know the performance of the executed query.

I can already get the statement plan (which index is used on the query) so the important values i am looking for is to see how performant the query is, how long does it take to prepare it, to execute it.

But if it is hard to do it's not really a problem, most of all i was curious where tools like Flamrobin, ibconsole, ibexpert get that info from.

Comment: Well, e.g. FlameRobin is open source. I can check how it's done there and post you an answer translated for FireDAC if it's fine for you.

Comment: Good idea, sure if you have time, thanks, i just got the source myself, i'll take a look at it too, although i don't know the Visual studio environment myself.

Comment: Well i am trying out some more about this, didn't really find anythign in Flamerobin source but thats probably because i don't know where to look.
Anyway i am trying out with iSql and reading in Helen Borries Firebird book, apparenelt you can indeed get this info with 'SET STATS', now the question remains if you can retrieve this with a Firedac query.